# Error in commiting to git saying stCommitMsg file not found

Tags: git

While trying to make a commit (with `git commit`) to my local git branch I got this error:

> fatal: could not read '/Users/<username>/.stCommitMsg': No such
> file or directory

Note that I am able to commit using the `-m` switch:

```
git commit -m "commit message"
```

but not without it:

```
git commit
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

When you run `git commit`, Git will read from the configure variable `commit.template` to find a *commit message template* and load it into your editor for you to write your commit message.

Regarding your error, it seems that Git is trying to find the template file `/Users/<username>/.stCommitMsg` - but it does not exist.

Check your configuration with:

```
git config --get commit.template
```

Double-check that your username is correct. If the file does not exist, you can create it with:

```
touch /Users/<username>/.stCommitMsg
```

Alternatively, you can edit `~/.gitconfig` and delete the `commit.template` item:

```
[commit]                                                                        
        template = /Users/<username>/.stCommitMsg
```

Comment: Great answer. For me, `.stCommitMsg` file and config settings came from SourceTree. I got this error when I migrated my `.gitconfig` to a new system without Sourcetree installed.

Answer (score 7):

Git is trying to find user defined git commit template. Either you can create an empty file at loc `'/Users/<username>/.stCommitMsg` or modify your `~/.gitconfig` to remove the template override.